# How to use Bootstrap 4 only on a specific Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a app that uses Bootstrap 3, unfortunate the Bootstrap 3 files (.css/js) have been heavily modified, my job is to include SummerNote Text editor, everything is working well but he style is really messed up due to the customisation that has been done previously,.. now is it possible to include and use Bootstrap 4 only on that specific modal?

below is the sample code! Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bootstrap4</title>

    <!-- My app uses Bootstrap 3 and has been heavily modified  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- My app uses Bootstrap 3 and has been heavily modified  -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Summer Note</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="summernote"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

   
    <script>
      $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder: '',
        tabsize: 2,
        height: 100
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. You can include it as a new document, using `<iframe>`. It's bascially a new page into your page. not inheriting any CSS from parent. It's blank.

Comment: that's unheard of...  is there any other 'clean way'?

Comment: Just because you haven't heard of it doesn't make it *unheard of*. And, really, that ***is*** the *"clean way"*.

Comment: trying it right now..

Comment: update: summernote wont render in an iframe

Comment: According to [their docs](https://github.com/summernote/summernote#why-summernote) they support both Bootstrap v3 and v4. So use v3 if you have v3 in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new file for modal and include summernote & bootstrap 4 in same page, add the new file to existing. note: include new file in bottom section so that it will not override the existing bs version style

Comment: This is might help you if your working on Js/Php project,